# Javascript substring replace and output

Tags: javascript, json, string

Hi guys I wonder how to reconstruct string. I need to replace br tag inside string with '\n' new line character. So I'm simply doing it like this:

```
let a='Some<br>Text'
let b=a.replace(/<br>/gi, '\n');
```

But when I try to make an output to console this way:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(b))
```

It shows the string like this:

```
Some\nText
```

But if I'm doing output this way:

```
console.log(b)
```

It returns:

```
Some
Text
```

So why? And is it possible to use console.log(JSON.stringify(b)) to show the string in a proper way. I mean like this:
Some
Text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the stringify method converts all the characters to string, so you wont see line breaks as expected. If you want to display your text on the same line, you can just replace (inside your regexp replacer) the newline `'\n'` with an empty space `' '`

Answer (score 0):

just replace br with  an empty space instead of \n, since \n means a new line.This is why your second word starts from new line

```
let a='Some<br>Text'
let b=a.replace(/<br>/gi, " ");
```

output

```
Some Text
```